# Cannot install pocketsphinx

Tags: python, python-wheel, pocketsphinx

Every time I try to install pocketsphinx by using:

```
pip install pocketsphinx
```

It gives me the following error, saying that it could not build the wheel:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pocketsphinx
  Building wheel for pocketsphinx (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pocketsphinx (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [320 lines of output]


      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143)" generator
      --------------------------------
      ---------------------------
      ----------------------
      -----------------
      ------------
      -------
      --
      Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
      -- The C compiler identification is unknown
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE):
        No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

        Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
        variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
        the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "C:/Users/meowm/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-gff822zn/pocketsphinx_800512f0fe9244099e86d0d402c4d8f2/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      See also "C:/Users/meowm/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-gff822zn/pocketsphinx_800512f0fe9244099e86d0d402c4d8f2/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
      --
      -------
      ------------
      -----------------
      ----------------------
      ---------------------------
      --------------------------------
      -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143)" generator - failure
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -- Trying "Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143" generator
      --------------------------------
      ---------------------------
      ----------------------
      -----------------
      ------------
      -------
      --
      Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
        Generator

          Visual Studio 17 2022

        could not find any instance of Visual Studio.



      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "C:/Users/meowm/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-gff822zn/pocketsphinx_800512f0fe9244099e86d0d402c4d8f2/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      --
      -------
      ------------
      -----------------
      ----------------------
      ---------------------------
      --------------------------------
      -- Trying "Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143" generator - failure
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142)" generator
      --------------------------------
      ---------------------------
      ----------------------
      -----------------
      ------------
      -------
      --
      Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
      -- The C compiler identification is unknown
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE):
        No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

        Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
        variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
        the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "C:/Users/meowm/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-gff822zn/pocketsphinx_800512f0fe9244099e86d0d402c4d8f2/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      See also "C:/Users/meowm/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-gff822zn/pocketsphinx_800512f0fe9244099e86d0d402c4d8f2/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
      --
      -------
      ------------
      -----------------
      ----------------------
      ---------------------------
      --------------------------------
      -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142)" generator - failure
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -- Trying "Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142" generator
      --------------------------------
      ---------------------------
      ----------------------
      -----------------
      ------------
      -------
      --
      Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
        Generator

          Visual Studio 16 2019

        could not find any instance of Visual Studio.



      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "C:/Users/meowm/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-gff822zn/pocketsphinx_800512f0fe9244099e86d0d402c4d8f2/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      --
      -------
      ------------
      -----------------
      ----------------------
      ---------------------------
      --------------------------------
      -- Trying "Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142" generator - failure
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141)" generator
      --------------------------------
      ---------------------------
      ----------------------
      -----------------
      ------------
      -------
      --
      Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
      -- The C compiler identification is unknown
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE):
        No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

        Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
        variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
        the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "C:/Users/meowm/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-gff822zn/pocketsphinx_800512f0fe9244099e86d0d402c4d8f2/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      See also "C:/Users/meowm/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-gff822zn/pocketsphinx_800512f0fe9244099e86d0d402c4d8f2/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
      --
      -------
      ------------
      -----------------
      ----------------------
      ---------------------------
      --------------------------------
      -- Trying "Ninja (Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141)" generator - failure
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141" generator
      --------------------------------
      ---------------------------
      ----------------------
      -----------------
      ------------
      -------
      --
      Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
        Generator

          Visual Studio 15 2017

        could not find any instance of Visual Studio.



      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "C:/Users/meowm/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-gff822zn/pocketsphinx_800512f0fe9244099e86d0d402c4d8f2/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      --
      -------
      ------------
      -----------------
      ----------------------
      ---------------------------
      --------------------------------
      -- Trying "Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141" generator - failure
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143)" generator
      --------------------------------
      ---------------------------
      ----------------------
      -----------------
      ------------
      -------
      --
      Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
        Running

         'nmake' '-?'

        failed with:

         The system cannot find the file specified


      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "C:/Users/meowm/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-gff822zn/pocketsphinx_800512f0fe9244099e86d0d402c4d8f2/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      --
      -------
      ------------
      -----------------
      ----------------------
      ---------------------------
      --------------------------------
      -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 17 2022 x64 v143)" generator - failure
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142)" generator
      --------------------------------
      ---------------------------
      ----------------------
      -----------------
      ------------
      -------
      --
      Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
        Running

         'nmake' '-?'

        failed with:

         The system cannot find the file specified


      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "C:/Users/meowm/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-gff822zn/pocketsphinx_800512f0fe9244099e86d0d402c4d8f2/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      --
      -------
      ------------
      -----------------
      ----------------------
      ---------------------------
      --------------------------------
      -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 16 2019 x64 v142)" generator - failure
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141)" generator
      --------------------------------
      ---------------------------
      ----------------------
      -----------------
      ------------
      -------
      --
      Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
        Running

         'nmake' '-?'

        failed with:

         The system cannot find the file specified


      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "C:/Users/meowm/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-gff822zn/pocketsphinx_800512f0fe9244099e86d0d402c4d8f2/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      --
      -------
      ------------
      -----------------
      ----------------------
      ---------------------------
      --------------------------------
      -- Trying "NMake Makefiles (Visual Studio 15 2017 x64 v141)" generator - failure
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

      ********************************************************************************
      scikit-build could not get a working generator for your system. Aborting build.

      Building windows wheels for Python 3.11 requires Microsoft Visual Studio 2022.
      Get it with "Visual Studio 2017":

        https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

      Or with "Visual Studio 2019":

          https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

      Or with "Visual Studio 2022":

          https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

      ********************************************************************************
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pocketsphinx
Failed to build pocketsphinx
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pocketsphinx, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I'm on windows 11 and I have python version 3.11, pip version 22.3.1. Even if i try to install it from github, it gives me an error saying that a function in distutils cannot be found.
Please help

Comment: I think you should revert to Python 3.10, which is the latest version `pocketsphinx` is building and testing as part of its CI workflows. Here are the artifacts with the windows build wheel: https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/suites/8909506011/artifacts/407996862